# How can I map a Foreign Key in EF Code First Fluent when the column name does not match the parent table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I would like to do mapping using the Fluent API. I saw some other examples but these look different to what I want to do.

Here is my SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE [Question] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_QuestionUserProfile] 
FOREIGN KEY([AssignedTo]) REFERENCES [UserProfile] ([UserId])
```

Which gives me this error message:

```
There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'UserProfile' 
that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_QuestionUserProfile'
Could not create constraint
```

I have two classes:

```
public class Question
{

    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int AssignedTo { get; set; }
    public int ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
}
public partial class UserProfile
{
    public UserProfile()
    {
        this.webpages_Roles = new List<webpages_Roles>();
    }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<webpages_Roles> webpages_Roles { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

I want to do the mapping between Question <> UserProfile so that:

- AssignedTo is mapped to UserId in UserProfile.
- Modified is mapped to UserId in UserProfile.

I have this so far in my QuestionMap

```
        this.HasRequired(t => t.UserProfile)
            .WithMany(t => t.Questions)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.AssignedTo);
        this.HasRequired(t => t.UserProfile)
            .WithMany(t => t.Questions)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.ModifiedBy);
```

But will this work as the ForeignKey has AssignedTo as the name in Question and UserId in UserProfile. Is 
there a way in the mappings that I can specify they should map to UserId ?

Comment: Do your UserId marked as primary key of UserProfile in fluent configs?

Comment: Yes it is the primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The foreign key and the primary key in the principal table doesn't have to have the same name. No problem to map `AssignedTo` to `UserId`. However you are trying to define *two* relationships and to do this you also need *two* navigation properties. You cannot use `UserProfile` as navigation property in both relationships nor can you use the `Questions` collection twice. You could change your `Question` entity like so (`UserProfile` can remain unchanged):

```cs
public class Question
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int AssignedTo { get; set; }
    public int ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual UserProfile AssignedToUser { get; set; }
    public virtual UserProfile ModifiedByUser { get; set; }
}
```

And then create this mapping:

```cs
this.HasRequired(t => t.AssignedToUser)
    .WithMany(t => t.Questions)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.AssignedTo);

this.HasRequired(t => t.ModifiedByUser)
    .WithMany() // <- don't use "t => t.Questions" here again
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.ModifiedBy)
    .WillCasadeOnDelete(false);
```

Cascading delete must be disabled for at least one of the two relationships. Otherwise SQL Server will complain about multiple cascading delete paths.

However this all won't probably fix the exception you had when creating the foreign key constraint. This error means that `UserProfile.UserId` is not the primary key in the `UserProfile` table (or generally it does not have a unique constraint). Maybe `UserId` is only part of a composite primary key (with `UserId`+`UserName` perhaps)?